# Installing locally and globally a npm depency produces an error while executing the command line

Tags: npm, package.json

I am trying to install locally and globally a npm depency by using `npm install -g .`.

The package.json seems to be ok :

```
{
  "private": true,
  ...
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "bin": {
    "gbts": "./dist/main.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
 ...
  "dependencies": {
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "ora": "^5.1.0",
    "ts2c": "^2.2.7",
    "yargs": "^16.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.9",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

This works perfetly, but when I invoke the command `gbts`, I still have this error pop in error on windows:

[image]

It occurs on the following line :

```
const parse = require("minimist");
```

I do not understand why this produce a syntax error, project's dependencies are missing?
Any solution in my case?

Comment: What node and npm version?

Comment: I am using node 12.18.3 and npm 6.14.6

Comment: I don't use Windows and this may very well be a Windows issue but have you tried using `npm link` instead of `npm install -g .`?

Comment: Yes, I still have the same issue.